# MySQL use results from one query in another

Tags: mysql

I have 2 queries:

```
SELECT m.* FROM (
    SELECT type, ROUND(
        COUNT(*) / ROUND(
            1000 / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM types)
        )
    ) AS nth FROM data GROUP BY type
) AS m;
```

and

```
SELECT d.* FROM (
    SELECT * FROM data 
    WHERE type = @id 
    AND time BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date
    ORDER BY time ASC
) d 
CROSS JOIN (select @i := 0) i
HAVING ( @i := @i + 1) MOD @nth = 1;
```

First query returns type "id" and "nth" value pairs that I would like to use in seconds query;

I need to some how iterate over first query values passing them in second query, how could I do that?

## EDIT:

The table I am working on contains log like this

```
+----+------+---------+---------------------+
| id | type | counter |        time         |
+----+------+---------+---------------------+
|  1 |    1 |   10001 | 2014-04-06 22:20:21 |
|  2 |    2 |   12354 | 2014-04-06 22:20:21 |
|  3 |    3 |   12456 | 2014-04-06 22:20:21 |
|  4 |    1 |   10101 | 2014-04-06 22:20:21 |
|  5 |    2 |   12454 | 2014-04-06 22:20:21 |
|  6 |    4 |   12679 | 2014-04-06 22:20:21 |
| .. |   .. |      .. |                  .. |
+----+------+---------+---------------------+
```

It contains massive amounts of data, I need to select data sample: Let's say I need to select +-1000 records, and there are e.g. 7 types, so I need to select ROUND(1000 / 7) = 143 rows for each type. Let's say type 1 has 1135135 records and type 2 has 935135, for each type I can select only 143 records so if selecting from begging to end (@start_date = minimum time value, @end_date = maximum time value), I would need to select from each type in equal intervals 143 rows. For example with type 1 that would be every ROUND(1135135 / 143) = 7938 record from list that contains only type 1 records, with type 2 logic would be the same ROUND(935135/ 143) = 6539nth

Comment: Thank you for your edit—that certainly helps us to understand what you are attempting to do.  However, this is not a task that MySQL will ever be able to perform efficiently; indeed, it will almost certainly require at least one full scan of your massive table.  Perhaps it's worth pausing for a moment to consider whether there is a more appropriate data structure, some simplifying heuristic or a proxy to the actual result that would satisfy your needs in a far more efficient manner.

Comment: For example, perhaps it is sufficient to divide the time interval into 143 slices and then select from each `type` the value that occurs closest to each time slice?

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot accomplish this with a subquery, then You cannot use results from one query in another without storing them first. As far as I know there are two ways you could do this:

You could use a temp table.  You would have to store the values of `id` and `nth` value pair in the temp table during your first query.  Then in you second query grap those values out again by joining on the temp table you just created.

creating a stored procedure using local variables. SO, In your first query you would store the `id` and `nth` value pairs `select`...`into` the local variables.  Then use those local variables in the second query.

Comment: "*You cannot use results from one query in another without storing those results somewhere*"—yes you can, e.g. `SELECT t.* FROM ( <another query> ) t` as shown in the question.

Comment: But subqueries **are** exactly how "using the results from one query with another query" can be accomplished.

Comment: I do want to combine those 2 queries, if using subquery would get the job done, i am all for it, but I l'v tries combining them, but couldn get result I needed